# How to get the size of an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

In C# I use the Length property embedded to the array I'd like to get the size of.
How to do that in C++?

Comment: Consider `std::array`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Arrays in C/C++ do not store their lengths in memory, so it is impossible to find their size purely given a pointer to an array. Any code using arrays in those languages relies on a constant known size, or a separate variable being passed around that specifies their size.

A common solution to this, if it does present a problem, is to use the [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) class from the standard library, which is much closer to a managed (C#) array, i.e. stores its length and additionally has a few useful member functions (for searching and manipulation).

Using `std::vector`, you can simply call `vector.size()` to get its size/length.

Comment: Is it impossible to get the size?

Comment: @John: Yes, it's impossible I'm afraid. See my updated answer. std::vector may be your best option.

Comment: That's my question,how to get the size of std::vector? It's just like an array.I'm sorry for misunderstanding,Im new to C++.

Comment: @John: Ah, fair enough. In C++ two types of "arrays" are commonly used - the native one, which is no more than a pointer really, and the std::vector class.

Comment: "for(int i = 0;i < entries.size;i++)" - Error :'<' : illegal, right operand has type '__w64 unsigned int (__thiscall std::vector<_Ty>::* )(void) const'

Comment: @John: `size` is a *member function* of the class, not a variable (or property, which doesn't exist in C++). You need to therefore add the brackets, i.e. `size()`.

Comment: I thought I had to use 64 bit integer,but the problem was in brackets. :) Thanks.

Comment: Use: for(size_t i = 0;i < entries.size();i++)

Answer (score 21):

It really depends what you mean by "array". Arrays in C++ will have a size (meaning the "raw" byte-size now) that equals to N times the size of one item. By that one can easily get the number of items using the `sizeof` operator. But this requires that you still have access to the type of that array. Once you pass it to functions, it will be converted to pointers, and then you are lost. No size can be determined anymore. You will have to construct some other way that relies on the value of the elements to calculate the size.

Here are some examples:

```
int a[5];
size_t size = (sizeof a / sizeof a[0]); // size == 5

int *pa = a;
```

If we now lose the name "a" (and therefor its type), for example by passing "pa" to a function where that function only then has the value of that pointer, then we are out of luck. We then cannot receive the size anymore. We would need to pass the size along with the pointer to that function.

The same restrictions apply when we get an array by using `new`. It returns a pointer pointing to that array's elements, and thus the size will be lost.

```
int *p = new int[5];
  // can't get the size of the array p points to. 
delete[] p;
```

It can't return a pointer that has the type of the array incorporated, because the size of the array created with `new` can be calculated at runtime. But types in C++ must be set at compile-time. Thus, `new` erases that array part, and returns a pointer to the elements instead. Note that you don't need to mess with `new` in C++. You can use the `std::vector` template, as recommended by another answer.

Comment: Did anyone mention ```std::extent``` yet?

Answer (score 6):

To count the number of elements in a static array, you can create a template function:

```
template < typename T, size_t N >
size_t countof( T const (&array)[ N ] )
{
    return N;
}
```

For standard containers such as `std::vector`, the `size()` *function* is used. This pattern is also used with [boost arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/array.html), which are fixed size arrays and claim no worse performance to static arrays. The code you have in a comment above should be:

```
for ( std::vector::size_type i(0); i < entries.size(); ++i )
```

( assuming the size changes in the loop, otherwise hoist it, ) rather than treating size as a member variable.

Comment: @Zingam the template? because a reference to an array preserves the type of the array, including the size, unlike a non-reference parameter which degrades to a pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I understand not half the template but I still cannot figure out why this statement works:  T const (&array)[ N ] The tutorials on templates I'm reading don't give me any clue.

Comment: @Zingam that parameter definition is a const reference to an array of `T`, the size of which is the template parameter `N`. The compiler deduces the type `T` and the size `N` from the compile-time type of the array passed into the function. The function then returns the value of `N`.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, arrays are simply pointers to the first element in the array, so there is no way to keep track of the size or # of elements. You will have to pass an integer indicating the size of the array if you need to use it.

Strings **may** have their length determined, assuming they are null terminated, by using the strlen() function, but that simply counts until the \0 character.

Comment: -1 Arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Als Nolrodin pointed out above, it is pretty much impossible to get the size of an plain array in C++ if you only have a pointer to its first element. However if you have a fixed-size array there is a well-known C trick to work out the number of elements in the array at compile time, namely by doing:

`GrmblFx loadsOfElements[1027];
GrmblFx_length = sizeof(loadsOfElements)/sizeof(GrmblFx);`