# Returning arrays from function and losing its size

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, methods

so let's say there is a function `int* coeff(int n)` that returns array (or rather, address to array[0]). Now, in this function this array has length of let's say 5, but when I call it like: `int* array=SomeObject->coeff(n);` that size is lost, and I don't know how can I get it back again. Any help please?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want a `std::vector`.

Comment: Before we continue, [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Or if you want to stick with arrays, just pass another reference to the function. And let the function set that variable to the size of the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the size of an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874169/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-array)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on it

Answer (score 1):

If you actually return a locally declared you have bigger problem than "losing its size".

First of all you have to remember that arrays decays to pointers, and once it has done that you no longer have any information about the array, just the pointer. And the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

The bigger problem might be you returning a locally declared array. When a function returns all variables declared locally in it goes out of scope. So what does the returned pointer then point to?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your code looks something like this:

```
int* coeff(int n)
{
    int* a = new int[5];
    // ...
    return a;
}
```

I suggest using a vector instead of an array:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> coeff(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> a(5);
    // ...
    return a;
}
```

You can always get the size of a vector by calling the `.size()` member function:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x = coeff(42);
    std::cout << x.size() << " elements in the vector!\n";
}
```